# Segfault when reading data from file to reallocating dynamic struct array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to read data from a file to a dynamic struct array, with the array size expanding via realloc to accommodate additional data.

It seems to work for a single line of data (array size 1), but anything larger and I get a segfault. I'm pretty inexperienced at coding, so I'm completely lost on what is causing it.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} Structure;

void Tester(Structure **Data)
{
    Structure Input; size_t Number = 0;

    *Data = NULL;

    FILE *File = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    while(2 == fscanf(File, "%d %d", &Input.a, &Input.b))
    {
        printf("Before: %d\n",Number);

        Number++;

        Structure *NewInput = realloc(*Data, Number * sizeof(Structure));

        *Data = NewInput;

        printf("After:  %d\n",Number);

        *Data[Number - 1] = Input;
    }

    fclose(File);
}

int main()
{
    Structure *TestData;

    Tester(&TestData);

    printf("%d %d", TestData[0].a, TestData[0].b);

    return 0;
}
```

The text file that I used contained just '1 2' when the program worked, and '1 2 3 4' when it didn't. The error occours at the line:

```
        *Data[Number - 1] = Input;
```

So I get the feeling that the realloc isn't working properly after the first loop. Any and all help or advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators. Use `(*Data)[Number - 1] = Input;`.

Comment: @EOF Post it as an answer

Comment: You should check if `fopen()` was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of operator precedence

```
*Data[Number - 1] = Input;
```

is equivalent to

```
*(Data[Number - 1]) = Input;
```

This is treating `Data` as an array of pointers, when it's actually a single pointer to another pointer that points to an array of `Structure`. It then uses the Nth element of this array (which doesn't really exist) as the location to copy `Input` to. It fails when `Number > 0` because none of these other pointers have been initialized (since there's no actual array there).

The correct syntax is:

```
(*Data)[Number - 1] = Input;
```

This dereferences `Data` to get to the array of `Structure` elements that you can assign to.

Comment: @immibis I think it was EOF, see our "discussion" in the comments to MikeCat's answer.

Comment: I originally downvoted that answer, but in deference to the fact that this is highly opinionated, I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

`*Data[Number - 1]` is equivalent to `Data[Number - 1][0]` because `[]` operator has higher precedence than unary `*` operator and `a[b]` is equivalent to `*((a) + (b))`, so `*Data[Number - 1]` = `*(Data[Number - 1])` = `*((Data[Number - 1]) + (0))` = `[Data[Number - 1][0]`

Also, `Data[1]` or above is out-of-range and it must not be accessed.

I guess you want `(*Data)[Number - 1]`, which is equivalent to `Data[0][Number - 1]`.

Comment: I think it would be less confusing if you said it's equivalent to `*(Data[Number - 1])`

Comment: I'm not sure why you would write it as `Data[0][Number - 1]`, since `Data` is not being used as an array, it's a pointer to an array.

Comment: @Barmar There is no array here.

Comment: @EOF That's my point. Using array indexing notation is confusing when there's no array. I know they're technically equivalent, but that's irrelevant; `*` is for dereferencing pointers, `[]` is for indexing arrays.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but written in such a way that it will be totally confusing to a new C programmer, which makes it effectively useless.

Comment: @Barmar: I mostly use `[]` on pointers (and not just because an array is a pointer when used as an operand to `[]`). In fact, I do much of my pointer arithmetic by `&ptr[n]`, rather than `ptr + n`. It is more readable.

Comment: @EOF That's fine when it's a pointer to a block of multiple items, because that's an array. But why would you use array notation when it's a pointer to a single thing, as in the poster's code?

Comment: @Barmar: Because for one, it's equivalent. Two, it doesn't require parentheses, because the associativity is obvious. Three, people need to learn about the relationship between pointers and arrays. Saying that `[]` is for arrays and `*` is for pointers is just needlessly confusing.

Comment: @EOF We'll have to agree to disagree, because I think that even though they're isomorphic, the concepts are very different. Yes, there are many C idioms that conflate them, so it's necessary to learn this, but you have to start with the basics.

Comment: @Barmar If you wanted to start with the basics, you'd stop mystifying the relationship between arrays and pointers, and just cite the standard (it's very readable in this instance): C11 draft standard n1570 *6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators, 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.*

Comment: How can you have been on SO for 2 years and have no clue what beginning programmers understand and what confuses them? This question is a perfect illustration, since it has a double indirection to an array.

Comment: @EOF Just wondering if you downvoted my answer because of your disagreement with me?

Comment: @Barmar: I can't claim to be free from personal biases, so I can't be sure the disagreement had nothing to do with it.